# unexpcted token while using react native linear gradient

Tags: react-native

So i am working on a component which i need to add linear gradient on `react-native-linear-gradient` but i am having this issue:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/react-native-linear-gradient/index.android.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: /Users/jimmy/Desktop/projects/numeric-input/node_modules/react-native-linear-gradient/index.android.js: Unexpected token, expected "," (8:36)
```

and

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/react-native-linear-gradient/index.ios.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: /Users/jimmy/Desktop/projects/numeric-input/node_modules/react-native-linear-gradient/index.ios.js: Unexpected token, expected "," (8:36)
```

[image]

Comment: 8th line 36th character is pointed as error. "," says it expects a comma. 
Can you edit as below please

`import NativeLinearGradient , { type , Props } from './common';`

Comment: If i do this change, i am pointed to other error within the same file

Comment: that's what we do when we write code :) resolve the error here and move on to the next error. do not give up. If you are going to take the right approaches to reach the right goal, the most you can do is move on to another mistake. Let's fix this error now. You can also share, I mean edit this post like cascade for the next error. I hope we can help

Comment: Getting this too, is anybody else encountering this?